# Excel formula to split and assighn value to each cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column in excel with the below values

[image: Problem Image]

Now I want to split that column into 4 columns with the values as below.

[image: Expected Result Image]

Am trying with Excel formulas using nested if with *AND*, *OR* and substitute, but not able to achieve it. Any suggestions/help on how can I get this ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Whenever someone answers your question you again add up another requirement. Instead you should provide all possible cases as sample in the question so that people can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to Your problem, if not this might move you to the correct answer, could be

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C$1,$A2)),IFERROR(MID($A2,FIND(C$1&" $ ",$A2)+6,LEN(C$1)),MID($A2,FIND(C$1&" $",$A2)+5,LEN(C$1))),0)`

Im assuming that your `Column 1` starts in `A1` and your first input is in `A2` further more im assuming headers `ABC, DEF...` are put in from `C1`. So putting this formula in `C2` you can drag this across and down.

The `IFERROR` handles the possibility that there is a space behind the `$`

Comment: Awesome... But this will give me only numbers rt? Because there are few numbers like $455M. meaning 455 Million. So i would like to keep the M at the end..

Comment: @Alan - You are right this gives only numbers because that is what you have asked in the question.

Comment: Ok.. I will accept this answer. Should i raise another question for the above value? Or can let me know here in this answer?

Comment: @Alan - As of now I can provide a dirty formula `=IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT($A2,LEN($A2)-FIND(B$1 & " $",$A2)-4),IFERROR(FIND(";",RIGHT($A2,LEN($A2)-FIND(B$1 & " $",$A2)-4))-1,LEN(RIGHT($A2,LEN($A2)-FIND(B$1 & " $",$A2)-4)))),"")`

Comment: @Alan - For above formula to work, your data should in `Column A` starting from Row 2, and `ABC, DEF, GHI, JKL` should in cells `B1, C1, D1, E1` respectively. Then enter formula in `Cell B2`, drag/copy down as across as required.

Comment: Thanks Mrig.. It Worked:)